# AddHttpClient<TClient,TImplementation> registers as transient, can it handle high volume concurrent requests efficiently?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I noticed that when using ASP.NET Core's `IHttpClientFactory`, the typed client registration method `AddHttpClient<TClient,TImplementation>` does two things:

1. It registers DI for `<TClient,TImplementation>` as transient, as if calling `services.AddTransient<TClient,TImplementation>` in startup.cs
2. It will inject a `HttpClient` instance of this registered type for each object initiated.

My concern is, if this is configured as transient, will it be able to handle a large number of concurrent `TImplementation` objects making http calls, because there will be a new `HttpClient` as well as a new  `TClient` created for every call? These clients will all access the same URL, will sockets be re-used properly?

Comment: Yes. The entire purpose of `IHttpClientFactory` is to manage your application's `HttpClient` objects efficiently to avoid socket starvation issues. If it didn't at least do that, then what would be the point of using `IHttpClientFactory` at all? :)

Comment: `HttpClient` is just a wrapper, the instantiation is fast. What reused behind the scene is `HttpMessageHandler` which is associated with a socket. So you don't have to care about that.

Comment: Do be careful, however, not to let the `TClient` become a Captive Dependency by injecting it directly or indirectly into a Singleton consumer. For more details, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68820007/is-a-singleton-httpclient-receiving-a-new-httpmessagehandler-after-x-minutes/68829519#68829519

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [King King](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679602/king-king) has already pointed out the `HttpMessageHandler` which matters.

To better understanding how does it work I suggest to examine the `DefaultHttpClientFactory`'s [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs).

Let's take a look at the [CreateClient](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs#L117) method:

```cs
public HttpClient CreateClient(string name)
{
    if (name == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
    }

    HttpMessageHandler handler = CreateHandler(name);
    var client = new HttpClient(handler, disposeHandler: false);

    HttpClientFactoryOptions options = _optionsMonitor.Get(name);
    for (int i = 0; i < options.HttpClientActions.Count; i++)
    {
        options.HttpClientActions[i](client);
    }

    return client;
}
```

As you can see it calls [CreateHandler](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs#L136):

```cs
public HttpMessageHandler CreateHandler(string name)
{
    if (name == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
    }

    ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry entry = _activeHandlers.GetOrAdd(name, _entryFactory).Value;

    StartHandlerEntryTimer(entry);

    return entry.Handler;
}
```

Here we have a pool of handlers via `_activeHandlers`. And a factory method `_entryFactory`, which is called when a given entry does not exist. Let's take a look at their definitions:

```cs
_activeHandlers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry>>(StringComparer.Ordinal);
_entryFactory = (name) =>
{
    return new Lazy<ActiveHandlerTrackingEntry>(() =>
    {
        return CreateHandlerEntry(name);
    }, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);
};

_expiredHandlers = new ConcurrentQueue<ExpiredHandlerTrackingEntry>();
```

So, as you can see it uses a `Lazy` structure to minimize the cost of the initializations.

The related `CreateHandlerEntry`'s source code can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs#L151) if you are interested.

I also suggest to read [Stephen Gordon's excellent article about this topic](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclient-creation-and-disposal-internals-should-i-dispose-of-httpclient).